# How do I make a picture populate the entire container keeping proper aspect ratio in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

It might be a simple issue, but, nevertheless, I've been scratching my head over it for quite a time now. 
This is the HTML

```
<div class="menuforpics">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/computer_programmer_profile_image.jpg" alt="jumbotron-img"/>
</div>
```

This is the customary CSS for the div:

```
.menuforpics{
background-color: black;
height: 90vh;
margin-top: 2%;
display: block;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Use flex for display of the div.

```
.menuforpics{
background-color: black;
height: 90vh;
margin-top: 2%;
display: flex;
flex-direction:row; 
justify-content:center;
```

}

And then apply some customary styling to the img.

```
#makeitresp{
height: 90vh;
width: auto;
```

}